# Disable elements inside of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have statement `$("#myDiv").attr("disabled","disabled");`
I thought that once I disable "parent" container, all elements inside of this become disabled. What I see actually, that text-box looks like disabled and "delete" not works within, but I can type there. check-box that inside of the same div, really looks disabled and I can't check/uncheck it. I'm not sure for 100%, but I think that I already used disabling that way and it worked as I expected (text-box not typeble). So I want to know if I need explicitly set disabled for textboxes or maybe some other CSS breaks what I'm expecting.

**UPDATE:**
I know how to set disable explicitly for elements that i need, I just not want tot do it and what I'm asking that if it the only way to disable it, or textbox may work exactly as checkbox  (without explicitly disabling it) and just some CSS breaks this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as im aware doing that is not cross browser friendly nor valid markup. Best option would be to do something like

```
$('#myDiv').find('input,textarea,select').attr("disabled", true);
```

That should find all form elements within the div and apply teh disabled flag directly

Edit: or even just

```
$('input,textarea,select', '#myDiv').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Or just $("#myDiv *").attr("disabled","disabled");

Comment: @Lee, thx, but I know how to set it explicitly, what I'm asking that if it the only way to disable it, or textbox may work exactly as checkbox and just some CSS breaks this behavior.

Comment: Actually `$('#myDiv').find(':input')...` seems to be the nicest way.

Comment: @Alex In the first sentence you get your answer. A `div` can have NO `disabled` attribute, it should not work theoretically.

Comment: adding attribute disabled simply applied disabled to the element. It is the browser that interprets it. Chrome for example does nothing when you disable a div. My method can be seen here

http://jsfiddle.net/ms4Hz/

Comment: @Lee What about `button`? I really think you should use the `:input` shortcut if jQuery provides it.

Comment: yeah if you find that easier, the reason i used what i did was so that Alex had more control over the elements and i think it makes it easier to understand. Some people aren't aware of all the custom selectors so they could interpret ":input" to mean only the input element. Either option is fine though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:input](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector:

`$("#myDiv :input").attr("disabled", true);`